# Using rest parameter to make functions adaptable in various contexts

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, variadic-functions

Noob programmer here,

I find myself using the rest parameter often, as a way of keeping my functions adaptable early when I don't know all the variables types/arguments.

I would like to develop a better understanding of its use in complex scenarios, unless it isn't meant to be used this way.

**function to set the max value as the first parameter used when arguments are known**

```js
function maxFirst1(min, max) { 
    if (min > max) {
        const temp = min;
        min = max;
        max = temp;
    }
}
```

**Same as above but arguments are not known, and `(...args)` used as placeholder**

```js
function maxFirst2(...args) {
    if (args.length <= 2) {
        //min & max tied to variables

        let min = args[0];
        let max = args[1];
        if (min > max) {
            const temp = min;
            min = max;
            max = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

**The other option is to simply use `array.sort` in this case**

```js
let arraySort = args.sort(compareFn);
  
  function compareFn(a, b) {
    return b - a;
  }
```

**I am using this early in my workflow when I don't know all the factors, but both methods achieve the same result.**

In terms of scalability, debugging, futureproofing etc, is `maxFirst2` the way to go, or are array methods like `arraySort` always better when working with `(...args)`? Or perhaps the rest parameter isn't designed with this kind of use in mind?

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Hard to say. When the parameters are the “same”, e.g., the max of a list of numbers, it makes sense. If they’re not, e.g., an address and suddenly an `addr2` then later an `addr3` are added, no, that’s awful.

Comment: As I moved on I began to understand that in most cases you're working with databases of information. I was trying to write resilient code with args as a way of working with unknown values, which really isn't necessary.

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score -2):

As I moved on I began to understand that in most cases you work with databases of information. I was trying to write resilient code with args as a way of working with unknown values, which really isn't necessary.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34033354)